# How do I transform this nested array of objects into a single array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, data-manipulation, purely-functional

I have this array of profile objects being returned by my api:

```
const profilesData = [
  {
    profile: { id: "26144385", some: "more", other: "misc" },
    photo_details: {
      photos: [{ small: "bar-1", medium: "baz-1" }]
    }
  },
  {
    profile: { id: "26144334", some: "even", other: "some more" },
    photo_details: {
      photos: [
        { small: "bar-2", medium: "baz-2" },
        { small: "fizz-2", medium: "buzz-2" }
      ]
    }
  }
];
```

I need to transform it so that I get a single `profileWithPhotos` array looks like this:

```
const profileWithPhotos = [
  {
    id: "26144385",
    some: "more",
    other: "misc",
    photos: [
      {
        small: "bar-1",
        medium: "baz-1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "26144334",
    some: "even",
    other: "some more",
    photos: [
      {
        small: "bar-2",
        medium: "baz-2"
      },
      {
        small: "fizz-2",
        medium: "buzz-2"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

So far I have tried breaking up the parsing into smaller functions:

```
const getProfiles = profilesData =>
  profilesData.map(profileData => profileData.profile);

const getSmallAndMediumPic = pic => ({ small: pic.small, medium: pic.medium });

const getPhotos = profilesData =>
  profilesData.map(profileData => profileData.photo_details.photos.map(getSmallAndMediumPic));

const profiles = getProfiles(profilesData);
const photos = getPhotos(profilesData);

const profileWithPhotos = [...profiles, { photos: photos }];
```

And now I get this kind of array of objects:

```
​​​​​[ { id: '26144385', some: 'more', other: 'misc' },​​​​​
​​​​​  { id: '26144334', some: 'even', other: 'some more' },​​​​​
​​​​​  { photos: [ [Object], [Object] ] } ]​​​​​
```

...which is not what I want.

Here is a [working jsbin](https://jsbin.com/laqihac/2/edit?js,console) with the code above

I want to pluck and combine the first extracted collection with the second extracted collection. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with some ES6 parameter destructuring and spread syntax in object.

```js
const profilesData = [{"profile":{"id":"26144385","some":"more","other":"misc"},"photo_details":{"photos":[{"small":"bar-1","medium":"baz-1"}]}},{"profile":{"id":"26144334","some":"even","other":"some more"},"photo_details":{"photos":[{"small":"bar-2","medium":"baz-2"},{"small":"fizz-2","medium":"buzz-2"}]}}]

const result = profilesData.map(({profile, photo_details: {photos}}) => {
  return {...profile, photos}
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and assemple a new object for each element of the array.

```js
const
    profilesData = [{ profile: { id: "26144385", some: "more", other: "misc" }, photo_details: { photos: [{ small: "bar-1", medium: "baz-1" }] } }, { profile: { id: "26144334", some: "even", other: "some more" }, photo_details: { photos: [{ small: "bar-2", medium: "baz-2" }, { small: "fizz-2", medium: "buzz-2" }] } }],
    result = profilesData.map(
        ({ profile: { id, some, other }, photo_details: { photos } }) =>
        ({ id, some, other, photos })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Or with [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for objects on forthcoming JS. This worrks with BABEL.

```js
const
    profilesData = [{ profile: { id: "26144385", some: "more", other: "misc" }, photo_details: { photos: [{ small: "bar-1", medium: "baz-1" }] } }, { profile: { id: "26144334", some: "even", other: "some more" }, photo_details: { photos: [{ small: "bar-2", medium: "baz-2" }, { small: "fizz-2", medium: "buzz-2" }] } }],
    result = profilesData.map(
        ({ profile, photo_details: { photos } }) =>
        ({ ...profile, photos })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

I feel a simple `map` iteration would do what you want.

```
const result = profilesData.map(data => {
  return {
    id: data.profile.id,
    some: data.profile.some,
    other: data.profile.other,
    photos: data.photo_details.photos
  }
})
console.log(result);

//result
[{
  id: "26144385",
  other: "misc",
  photos: {
     medium: "baz-1",
     small: "bar-1"
  }],
  some: "more"
}, {
  id: "26144334",
  other: "some more",
  photos: {
     medium: "baz-2",
     small: "bar-2"
  }, {
     medium: "buzz-2",
     small: "fizz-2"
  }],
  some: "even"
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just loop through the profilesData array and create a new array that reconstructs the object with the attributes you need. Something like..

```
var data = [];
for(var i=0;i<profilesData.length;i++){
    data[i] = profilesData[i].profile;
    data[i].photos = profilesData[i].photo_details.photos
}
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#map` and `array#reduce` with `Object.assign()`

```js
const profilesData = [ { profile: { id: "26144385", some: "more", other: "misc" }, photo_details: { photos: [{ small: "bar-1", medium: "baz-1" }] } }, { profile: { id: "26144334", some: "even", other: "some more" }, photo_details: { photos: [ { small:"bar-2", medium: "baz-2" }, { small: "fizz-2", medium: "buzz-2" } ] } } ],
    result = profilesData.map(o => Object.values(o).reduce((r,o) => Object.assign(r, o), {}));
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straightforward:

```
profilesData.map(data => Object.assign({}, data.profile, { photos: data.photo_details.photos }));
```

Or, if you're only targeting the most recent environments or you're transpiling with e.g. Babel, you can make this even more succinct with [parameter destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter) and [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Spread_in_object_literals):

```
profilesData.map(({profile, photo_details: {photos}}) => ({ ...profile, photos }));
```

You can see both in action in the below snippet.

```js
const profilesData = [
  {
    profile: { id: "26144385", some: "more", other: "misc" },
    photo_details: {
      photos: [{ small: "bar-1", medium: "baz-1" }]
    }
  },
  {
    profile: { id: "26144334", some: "even", other: "some more" },
    photo_details: {
      photos: [
        { small: "bar-2", medium: "baz-2" },
        { small: "fizz-2", medium: "buzz-2" }
      ]
    }
  }
];

const profilesWithPhotos = profilesData.map(data =>
  Object.assign({}, data.profile, { photos: data.photo_details.photos }));

console.log(profilesWithPhotos);
console.log('-----');

const profilesWithPhotos2 =
  profilesData.map(({profile, photo_details: {photos}}) => ({ ...profile, photos }));

console.log(profilesWithPhotos2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%}
```

Comment: Note: I added the second bit of code after others had posted very similar answers, but I had not read them at the time I wrote it. Great minds and all that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems to be late but I think this will work
```

```
const transformedProfilesData = profilesData.reduce((array, object) => {
  const profile = {...object.profile}
  const photos = object.photo_details.photos.map(photo => photo)
  profile.photos = photos
  array.push(profile)
  return array
}, [])
```

```